# Ошибка в редиректах с GET параметрами

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно реализовать редирект с;

```
/sorting/restaurants.php
```

на:

```
/sorting/restaurants.php?brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D=%25`
```

Вот такие варианты я пробовал, но они не работают:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sorting/$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D=%25
RewriteRule ^.*$ /restaurants? [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sorting/restaurants$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D=%25
RewriteRule ^.*$ /sorting/restaurants [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$                  
RewriteRule ^restaurants\.php /restaurants.php?brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D=%25 [R=301,L]   

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D=%25
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /restaurants.php? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sorting/restaurants.php$ /sorting/restaurants.php?brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D=%25 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но после переадресации страница выдает ошибку..

Comment: Кажется я лишний слеш накопировал `RewriteRule ^sorting/restaurants.php$ sorting/restaurants.php?brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D=%25 [R=301,L]`

Comment: нет, тот слеш нужен

Comment: Так ошибка редиректа или РНР?

Comment: пишет `Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.` в каждом браузере так пишет

Comment: Попробуйте убрать опцию `R=301`, оставить только `L`

Comment: так тоже ошибку выдает, но уже другую...

Comment: я понял в чем ошибка, но как исправить...есть один вариант и все, суть ошибки в том, что переходя на `sorting/restaurants.php?brands%5B%5D=restaurants&brand%5B%5D‌​=%25` он снова запускает редирек  так как идет совпадение вот этой части `sorting/restaurants`, я вижу тут только один вариант, это переехать с  `sorting`  допустим на `sortin` и тогда все работает